# ファイルを添付してメールを送信したい

Tags: android, ios, monaca, html5, pdf

monaca利用でアプリ開発中です。
アプリ内でメールを起動してファイル添付したいのですが、やり方がわかりません。

メールを起動して件名、本文等を記述して送信するというのはこちらで教えていただいてできました(mailtoなどの利用）。
下記プラグインのDraft with Attachmentも試してみたのですが端末で反応しません(monacaプレビューでも反応なし）。
https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-email-composer

どなたか教えてください。大変困っています。よろしくお願いします。

補記）コメントいただきありがとうございます。端末内でファイル生成します。

Comment: メール本文に添付したいファイルのURLを記載できれると回避できそうですが、添付したいファイルは アプリが動作している iOS 端末上にあるものですか？

Comment: @turutoiya　上記のプラグインは動作し、png、jpegなどの画像ファイルは添付できるのですが、pdfは添付できません。どうしたらいいでしょうか。

Comment: pdf の添付、問題があったようですね。 https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-email-composer/issues/33
が、 https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-email-composer/issues/33#issuecomment-58580214 によると、→に pdfを添付するサンプルのあるので参考になるようです。 https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-email-composer/tree/example